# How can I add horizontal line in between radio button list item in mvc razor

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

[image]

How can I add horizontal line in between radio button list item in mvc razor

Comment: You could do it with CSS

Answer (score 0):

In your css file for `li`, write the css:

```
ul>li{
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```